# How to mux (intercept) net (tcp) sockets in node.js?

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, muxer

I want to look at headers on the first packet of a net socket connection and then decide what to do with it from there.

### TCP Example (works, but useless)

This is useless because it doesn't solve my problem, it just demonstrates that, in theory, the problem is solvable.

```
'use strict';

var net = require('net');
var http = require('http');

var http80 = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.end('Hello, World!');
});

var tcp80 = net.createServer(function (socket) {

  socket.once('data', function (chunk) {

    if (/http\/1/i.test(chunk.toString())) {
      console.log("looks like http, continue");
      http80.emit('connection', socket);
    } else {
      console.log("looks like tcp, die");
      socket.end();
    }

    socket.pause();
    process.nextTick(function () {
      socket.emit('data', chunk);
      socket.resume();
    });
  });

});

tcp80.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('listening on 80');
});
```

### TLS Example (doesn't work)

This is what I'm actually trying to do, but doesn't work:

```
'use strict';

var net = require('net');
var sni = require('sni');
var https = require('https');
var tlsOpts = require('localhost.daplie.com-certificates').merge({});

var https443 = https.createServer(tlsOpts, function (req, res) {
  res.end('Hello, Encrypted World!');
});

var tcp443 = net.createServer(function (socket) {

  // looking at the first packet, this is the gold
  socket.once('data', function (chunk) {

    // undo the read, more or less
    socket.pause();
    process.nextTick(function () {
      socket.emit('data', chunk);
      socket.resume();
    });

    if (/^tcp\.example\.com/i.test(sni(chunk))) {
      console.log("TODO: handle as raw tls / tcp");
      return;
    }

    console.log("handling as https");
    https443.emit('connection', socket);
  });

});

tcp443.listen(443, function () {
  console.log('listening on 443');
});
```

I've tried manually emitting the `readable` event as well as manually emitting the `data` event with the chunk and `resume`ing, but it just seems to hang in all of those cases rather than working like in the example above.

Comment: I've written a module years ago that might be of help (perhaps not directly, but it could give you an idea on how it might be implemented): [`port-mux`](https://github.com/robertklep/node-port-mux).

Comment: @robertklep I've actually already looked at that code earlier today. You're forwarding to a socket in an external process. I'm trying to reuse the same socket internally. Thanks for chiming in though. :)

Comment: Yeah, my code is more of a proxy in that respect. It's not a viable solution for you to create two servers _and_ a muxer (in the same process)? The muxer doesn't care where the server to forward to is created, can be the same process.